# Unable to make JDBC Connection ["jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/practiceDB"]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am new to hibernate. While running my first program I am facing 2 errors.

Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] and

Unable to make JDBC Connection ["jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/practiceDB"]

[image]

Dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.29</version>
    </dependency>
```

JAVA code

```
Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
    cfg.configure();
    SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();

    System.out.println(factory);
```

Comment: Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.
Also it's going to be the proper log file you should be posting as the full exception trace should be shown

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace **as text**.

Comment: @No Name, is it a requirement that you use hibernate directly? If not, look at https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

As @Reg mentioned in a comment below my post, the following approach is only applicable when also using the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency, so if you are not bound to use hibernate directly, feel free to include the dependency and follow the approach down below.
Also, a guide that is worth reading that also helped me a lot [Introduction to Spring Data JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa)

When using Spring you don't always need to write a configuration class for your database connection (atleast if you only have one single datasource).

You can simply configure your datasource via your `application.properties` or `application.yaml` file.

Try adding this to your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/practiceDB
spring.datasource.username=yourUsername
spring.datasource.password=yourPassword
```

Or adding this to your `application.yaml` file:

```
spring:
 datasource:
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/practiceDB
  username: yourUsername
  password: yourPassword
```

This should allow you to establish a connection to your datasource.

Comment: I believe this is only applicable when the user uses spring-boot-data starter-jpa

Comment: True! I totally forgot about that dependency.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Hibernate uses its internal database connection pool library. That means it keeps a database connection open to be reused later. And MySQL database server has a timeout value for each connection (default is 8 hours or 28,800 seconds). So if a connection has been idle longer than this timeout value, it will be dropped by the server.
Therefore, when the Java database application has been idle longer than MySQL server’s connection timeout value, and the end user tries to connect again, Hibernate reuses the idle connection which was already dropped by the server, hence JDBCConnectionExceptionis thrown.

Expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application:
This requires changing or re-structuring the existing code, which is difficult to implement. Furthermore, opening a database connection is an expensive operation so it’s not optimal to open and close database connection for every user’s request - that’s why database connection pooling comes into play.